# Use Wii Remote as presentation clicker

Tags: macos, remote-control, iwork-keynote, wii

I would like to use a Wii remote with my Macbook pro to control Keynote for presentations, primarily using A for next slide and B for previous. I prefer a free program, as I have a perfectly good mouse that works, it just doesn't have the Geek Factor :).

I'm aware of [Darwiin remote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/), but the project hasn't been updated in over a year and a half, and the software isn't very stable/reliable for me: half the time it doesn't connect to my remote, the other half it just plain crashes. I've heard it doesn't work at all on Snow Leopard, which I'll probably be upgrading to soon.

Are there any good free alternatives?

Comment: Pity you need this for a Mac. I worked on a GlovePIE script to use the wiimote during a presentation, which was not only using buttons, but also could use the pointer to draw on the slide (using powerpoint, at least). Unfortunately, GlovePIE is only for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [WiiNote](http://primatelabs.ca/wiinote/) from Primate Labs? (They make Geekbench)

Comment: +1 because it helped me resolve the issue I had with DarwiinRemote (was trying to power on then use 1+2, when just 1+2 sufficed).

Answer (score 0):

[Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) is *not* free, but it does come with a 30-day free trial. So you could probably have some fun with that for a month. :)

I haven't tried it with a Wii remote, but apparently it works.